# c# PropertyGrid double click

Tags: c#, events, propertygrid, double-click

I have made a dialog system similar to windows forms.
Like windows forms designer, I use a PropertyGrid for the properties and events.
What I would like is to make it so that when an event value is double clicked, a default value is filled if nothing was filled before, and I have to be able to transfer focus to another place in my application.

Anyone know how this could be achieved?

Answer (score -2):

Handling doubleclicks in the PropertyGrid is a bit tricky:

Here are some posts that may get you started:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/1c82666d-ea86-49a6-8844-079cff196275/

[Property grid item and DoubleClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362535/property-grid-item-and-doubleclick)

Comment: Well, I found those on google before posting.. I don't see how they help much. Neither of them want to do something when the property is double clicked (other than cycle through the values of their bool/enum). So they don't explain how to get a default value when a string property is double clicked, and they don't explain how to get an event when it is double clicked.

Comment: Why you don't just put the default value in the property to begin with?